# Replace HTML tags with newline using awk or sed

Tags: html, windows, sed, awk, newline

I have a large file with NO line feeds or carriage returns. The file came from HTML and I have stripped away all of the tags except the  that I want to convert to a newline character(/n). What is a quick and easy way to do this using either AWK or SED? I suppose that AWKSED is also an option.

Comment: Tell me there isn't really something named `AWKSED`!!!! Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>/\n/g' file
```

This means: replace all text starting with `<`, followed by an unspecified number of characters that are not `>`, and that ends with `>`, with a newline character.

Comment: So if I put /tr in the brackets, it should replace ALL occurrences of that tag with the newline?

Comment: Yes this will update all the occurrences with the newline, because of the `g` command, and because `[^>]` does a non-greedy match

Comment: I am a bit confused by your changes. if the tag is /tr, what do I replace in your solution with the /tr? The ^>, or the *?

Comment: @DominicRomano I added an explanation how it works. I assume the tag would be `</tr>` instead of `/tr`, so it would be matched by the command I posted (My initial answer did greedy matching, so it would only work for a single tag in the line)

Comment: @DominicRomano I just noticed that you have tagged the question with `[windows]`. If that is the case perhaps you should open the output with an editor that recognises `\n` as a newline, or change the command to `sed 's/<[^>]*>/\r\n/g' file`